# jquery replace part of a url

Tags: jquery, url-rewriting

I know practically nothing about jquery so please help me

I try this

```
function googlemapLinks {
 $('div.gmnoprint a').attr("href").replace('ll','q');
}
```

it does not work
I have a `<div class="gmnoprint">` In that div Google maps puts a javascript link in
maps.google.com/maps?ll=5.....
I need maps.google.com/maps?q=5.....

Can you show me a function I can drop in a script file?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
function googlemapLinks { 
    var lnk = $('div.gmnoprint a').attr("href");
    $('div.gmnoprint a').attr("href",lnk.replace('ll','q')); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you d and TheVillageIdiot. Looks very feasable but it's not working... maybe because it googlemap is written in by javascript already and not as html?

Is it maybe possible to grab that url with ll in it and append it to text underneath and then replace with q
function appendMap() {
 if ($('.block-gmap_location').length > 0) {
  $('.block-gmap_location').append($('<p>See this on <a href="url-from-googlemap">Google maps</a></p>'));
 }

Comment: if it's not working, it's probably because `$('div.gmnoprint a')` is empty at the time the code is executed. make sure that `googlemapLinks()` is called after the map has been shown, at a point when you're sure that it exists. try just typing out `javascript:alert($('div.gmnoprint a').length);` in your browser's address field, to make sure that the selector is working and returning any items at all

Answer (score 1):

For setting a value with `attr`, you need to pass the new value as a second parameter. try this:

```
$('div.gmnoprint a').attr('href', $('div.gmnoprint a').attr('href').replace('ll','q'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the conversation but you could try:

```
$('.gmnoprint a').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace('ll','q');
})
```

The other functions seem to loop whereas this will find the link and then replace '11' with 'q'. Well, it should =P

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change any link or a tag href inside the gmnoprint container. If you don't use the each loop all the hrefs will contain the first instance of the href on the page.
this code looks at each a tag and replaces just that instance if it runs into 11 and changes the text to q

```
$('.gmnoprint a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('11','q'));
});
```